# ' invalid destination position for blit' Projectiles Error How Do I fix This?

Tags: python, html, pygame

I was making my projectile class and I am getting this error

```
window.blit(self.slash,self.color,self.rect)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit
```

here is my projectile class

```
class projectile(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y,color):
       self.slash = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
       self.rect  = self.slash.get_rect()
       self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
       self.speed = 10
       self.color = color

   def draw(self, window):
       window.blit(self.slash,self.color,self.rect)

   def moveTo(self, x, y):
       self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I fixed it, it was quit simple

```py
class projectile(object): 
   def __init__(self, x, y,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.slash = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
       self.rect  = self.slash.get_rect()
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x, self.y )
       self.speed = 10
       self.color = color

   def draw(self, window):
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x,self.y )
       window.blit(self.slash,self.rect)
```